# Cycle Through Array To Populate Collection View

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I am currently making a weather app and would like to populate a collection view with the weather for the day. The data is set up in an array like this:

> [["2018-07-19 18:07951670925:07951670925", "cloudy2", "22"], ["2018-07-19 21:00:00", "cloudy2", "18"], ["2018-07-20 00:00:00", "cloudy2", "15"], ["2018-07-20 03:00:00", "cloudy2", "13"], ["2018-07-20 06:00:00", "cloudy2", "16"], ["2018-07-20 09:00:00", "cloudy2", "21"]]

For my collection view cell, I have a function that populates 2 labels and an image view

```
cell.dispayContent(time: string, image: UIImage(named: string), temperature: string)
```

I need a way of cycling through the array and adding the relevant info into the cells. I have tried this:

```
cell.dispayContent(time: todayModel.todayArray[indexPath][0], image: UIImage(named: todayModel.todayArray[indexPath][1])!, temperature: todayModel.todayArray[indexPath][2])
```

But get the error 'Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String]]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath` I guess (or `indexPath.section`, but that's rare)? But clearly, I wouldn't use an array of array of `String`. I'd use a custom struct/class. It make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `indexPath.row` instead of `IndexPath` as below,

```
let today = todayModel.todayArray[indexPath.row]
cell.dispayContent(time: today[0], image: UIImage(named: today[1])!, temperature: today[2])
```